# Failover with distributed queue

Tags: java, rabbitmq, jms, activemq-classic, ibm-mq

I have a distributed queue DQ1; with DQ1 I have 3 physical queues – Q1, Q2 and Q3. Now, suppose a queue consumer (QC1) created a receive request and it got pinned/connected with Q2, now suppose after some time Q2 got failed, then since QC1 is pinned/connected to Q2 so what will happen?

I read about this and I came to know that theoretically the QC1 will get a "JMSException", but I am not sure how? That JMS server in which Q2 was hosted suddenly crashed and other queues Q1 and Q3 will have no information about this QC1 so how QC1 can get exception (let's say QC1 is async consumer) and does it means that this QC1 will no more get any messages?

Also, what happens when Q2 comes back online, will it will have that QC1 information and will be able to send any message it received to QC1?

Also, please mention if this behaviour can be different for different JMS providers - for example, Weblogic JMS, ActiveMQ, RabbitMQ, IBM-MQ etc.

---

**Update:** As per @PeterNordlander it would be different per JMS provider, if that is the case then I would like know about Weblogic and ActiveMQ, if not all.

Comment: There is no way to tell. it will be different per JMS Provider and even different based on the choice of clustering, persistence storage, persistent delivery etc. You need to come up with a specific question for a specific provider.

Comment: @PetterNordlander Oh ok, I have updated my question.

Comment: What do you mean by "distributed queue"?  Are you using network of brokers?  Is this a CompositeQueue?

Comment: @MattPavlovich https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/jms/dds.html#1260811